# ASP.NET MVC4 - Session_End - How can I get the currently logged on user's name in Session_End of Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-state, global-asax, httpcontext

My issue is that once Session_End executes in my Global.asax, the `HttpContext.Current` object no longer exists- probably as expected, I would imagine.  So, what I'm trying to do is once the session ends, update my Logins table for the user currently logged in and set their LoggedIn status to False.  Here's my Session_End:

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Helpers.OperationContext.UpdateIndividualLogin();
}
```

As you can probably guess, I can try to pass in:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

But this object no longer exists because I can only imagine that it's already been disposed of.  So, is there any way I can grab the currently (or previously current) user's name?

Comment: Just a comment: If you are considering to later deploy to a web-farm or use session-state in sql server or other variants, beware that the Session_End event may not trigger on some of those configurations

Comment: Thanks for that piece of information. My research tonight came across that info as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by storing the information you want (in this case the user name) in Session.  You can store it when the user is authenticated.